# Need help in navigation in header my web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to make selected links vsible on top of page, like this , "home > page1 > link1> article 1" how can i make this using html php or jquery

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please remember that StackOverflow is not a coding service

Comment: Do some research on breadcrumbs.

Comment: thank you for replies. It solved my problem. I wanted to know the terminology the process  is called by that is " breadcrumpbs" . thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used Proper URL hierarchy for navigation

**PHP code**:

```
<?php

// This function will take $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and build a breadcrumb based on the user's current path
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
    // This gets the REQUEST_URI (/path/to/file.php), splits the string (using '/') into an array, and then filters out any empty values
    $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));

    // This will build our "base URL" ... Also accounts for HTTPS :)
    $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

    // Initialize a temporary array with our breadcrumbs. (starting with our home page, which I'm assuming will be the base URL)
    $breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");

    // Find out the index for the last value in our path array
    $last = end(array_keys($path));

    // Build the rest of the breadcrumbs
    foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
        // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));

        // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
        if ($x != $last)
            $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";
        // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
        else
            $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
    }

    // Build our temporary array (pieces of bread) into one big string :)
    return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
}

?>

<p><?= breadcrumbs() ?></p>
<p><?= breadcrumbs(' > ') ?></p>
<p><?= breadcrumbs(' ^^ ', 'Index') ?></p>
```

Where define a function in the header and use function wherever you want to show.

**jQuery Code**:

```
var here = location.href.split('/').slice(3);

var parts = [{ "text": 'Home', "link": '/' }];
var breadcrumb = [];
for( var i = 0; i < here.length; i++ ) {
    var part = here[i];
    var text = part.toUpperCase();
    var link = '/' + here.slice( 0, i + 1 ).join('/');
    parts.push({ "text": text, "link": link });
}
```

where create html by `parts` array and add to wherever you want.